# populate post meta in gravity forms

Tags: post-meta, plugin-gravity-forms

I can populate post author email with this code:

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_author_email', 'populate_post_author_email');
function populate_post_author_email($value){
    global $post;

    $author_email = get_the_author_meta('email', $post->post_author);

    return $author_email;
}
```

It's ok, but how i can populate meta of post? meta = imail

I'm trying with

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_meta_imail', 'populate_post_meta_imail');
function populate_post_meta_imail($value){
    global $post;

    $meta_imail = get_post_meta('imail', $post->post_id);

    return $meta_imail;
}
```

Comment: Gravity Forms is commercial software, meaning that the source is unavailable to us and meaning that the question is off-topic. Contact the plugin's author.

Comment: @s_ha_dum this is not about gravity forms, is about get post_meta. And plugin-gravity-forms is a valid Tag

Comment: And "code with restricted access" is an explicitly listed valid reason to close a question.

Comment: I don't understand good yet the rules of this site sorry. I'm spanish and i don't understand english very well. But i'm learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments for `get_post_meta` backwards. You have:

```
get_post_meta('imail', $post->post_id);
```

Whereas, [where you to check the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), it should be:

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
```

Or is your case:

```
get_post_meta($post->post_id,'imail');
```

That is assuming that `$post` is set correctly and that you are using the Gravity Forms hooks correctly.